# How to assign value to a 2d array from reference in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int max(int x,int y){
if(x>=y)
 return x;
else
 return y;
             }
int calci(int i,int j,int n,int *c){
int k,y,m;
k=j;
y = (n)/((2^i)*(2^j));
for(y=i;y>=0;y--){
for(k=j;k>=0;k--){
 *(*(c+2)+k) = max(y,calci(i+1,k,n,c)+calci(i+2,k,n,c)+calci(i,k+1,n,c));   
    }
 for(y=0;y<=j+2;y++){
 *(*(c+1)+y)=*(*(c+2)+y);
*(*(c+0)+y)=*(*(c+1)+y);
}
}
 return *(*(c+2)+0);
 }


int main(){
int i,j,n,z,x,y;
printf("Enter the amount\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
x=log(n)/log(2);
y=log(n)/log(3);
int arr[3][y+3];
for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
for(j=0;j<=y;j++)
arr[i][j+2]=0;
z = calci(x,y,n,arr);
printf("\n%d",z);
}
```

Here I get error as invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int'). I am actually trying to assign the value returned by max function as array element of row 2 and column k.

Comment: `c` is not a 2d array. To pass a 2d array to the function, use at least `int **c`. Then `c[0]` points to the first subarray.

Comment: Looks like you are doing two dereferences on a one-star pointer.  I would guess you are treating it like an array of arrays rather than a 2D array.

Comment: There is no 2D array here.  Post code that calls `calci()`, an [MCVE] is even better.

Comment: What is being passed in  as arg `c`?

Comment: I have added the calling function. Please check

Comment: Add the  `max()` definition also. And what `calci()` supposed to return to `main()` ?

Comment: Added max() and calci()

Comment: You changed the function signature of `calci`.  You should not do this as it invalidates previous comments.

Comment: but still `int arr[3][y+3]` doesn't match `int **c`

Comment: Please indent!!

Comment: ^^^^ this is sensibly unreadable.

Comment: The single-letter var names do not help with readabilty:(

Comment: Why do beginners think it is cool to write `*(*(c+2)+k)` instead of `c[2][k]`, which is simpler, shorter, and harder to get wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing two dereferences on a one-star pointer.  What you are attempting to do is treat it as an array of arrays, but what you are passing in is a 2D array that decays to a pointer.  A 2D array is a single contiguous block of memory that can be address with arithmetic to calculate the cell you want.  For an N x M matrix, if you want element [w][x], you can do arr[N*w + x].  Or with a modern C standard, you can adjust your function signature to be like this and access the array as normal:

```
int calci(int i, int j, int n, c[i][j])
```